# java unexpected and unaccountable break of loop

Tags: java, loops

Let compare this two methods...

### Case 1: function working correctly

```
public void fooTestOk() {
    boolean ret = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        boolean r;

        if (fooIf(i))
            r = fooMethod(i);
        else 
            r = fooMethod(i);

        ret = ret && r;
    }
    System.out.println("ret "+ret);
}
```

#### Output

It give me following expected output (I have cuted newlines):

`0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
ret false`

### Case 2: function that makes unexpected break

But this method

```
public void fooTestFail() {
    boolean ret = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        if (fooIf(i))
            ret = ret && fooMethod(i);
        else 
            ret = ret && fooMethod(i);      
    }
    System.out.println("ret "+ret);
}
```

#### Output

Give me only this output, the loop had to be broke! There was no exception!

`0
ret false`

Could anybody explain why in this case **loop was terminated without any error**?

### Rest of code

Here are my `fooIf` and `fooMethod` functions:

```
public boolean fooIf(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

public boolean fooMethod(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
    return i == 5;
}
```

Comment: I would change `ret = ret && fooMethod(i);` to `ret &= fooMethod(i);`

Comment: @ars265 That is not equivalent (and would result in the output of sample 1).

Comment: @assylias, He said that was the expected result, so yes, the same as sample 1, am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&&` is short circuit. That means that if in `a && b`, `a` evaluates to `false`, `b` isn't evaluated anymore. So, the loop doesn't break. What is happening is that `fooMethod` is not called, because `ret` gets `false` after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your function actually does not break, `fooMethod(i)` is just not called anymore because `&&` is short circuit.

That means that the second expression in only evaluated if needed. If you have `false && x` you do not have to know what value `x` has because the result will always be `false`.

In your case `ret` turns to `false` after the first iteration. Therefor the return value of `fooMethod(i)` is irrelevant and the method is not called.

Try to change `ret = ret && fooMethod(i);` to `ret = ret & fooMethod(i);`.
The result will be the same as in your first case.

Answer (score 1):

your statement `ret = ret && fooMethod(i);` is setting ret = to false because fooMethod(i), when i = 0 (first time through the loop) returns false.

fooMethod(i) prints 0 to the screen, returns a false value and sets `ret = ret && fooMethod(i)` which is the same as saying 'ret = true && false` which returns false.

Once ret is false after the first iteration of the loop the program needs not run the fooMethod because regardless of what comes back the result will be false, because ret is already false:

`ret = false && //doesn't matter what else, ret is false`

this means your loop runs the first time, printing out 0 and every iteration thereafter fails to change the value of ret. Once it's done it prints ret and false

Comment: Once again I'm too slow, looks like everybody answered this already heh.